# How to login to SSH using a .pub key file and a password?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm about to connect to a remote using SSH but I'm lost at doing this. I thought I get it but I'm not be been able to connect.

The client provided me the following information via email (I have no control of the remote site and I'm not the admin)

- .pub file
- SSH password
- SSH username
- Key type: DSA
- Key Size: 1024
- Hostname

I'm assume its port 22 (default for SSH). I remember some months ago I was able to connect with:

```
ssh -i /path_to_key_file username@remotehost.com
```

But this will work if its a private key file right? Do I have the right information to connect? What are the steps to connect successfully via a command line?

Comment: You need a corresponding private key to the public one. Do you have that?

Comment: No I don't have the private key, so I need that right?

Comment: Well, if you were sent a public key then I assume you would. On the other hand, you were sent login and password which suggests that there is *no* key encryption. Have you tried connecting with login and password only? Otherwise I suggest you get that private key...

Comment: Nope, username and password only does not work..I think i should get the private key..Thanks.

Comment: Just don't let your client send it through mail ;) I've rephrased my comments into an answer. Please accept it if you feel it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have public *and* private key or you login with username and password. Seeing that you received a public key file it's likely that you have to use key authentication to login. For that you'll need a private key of course. 
But since your client also sent you a login and password you could try logging in without key authentication.

In short: your client is probably not completely comfortable with configuring shhd...